# Jest failing to run tests when importing globals

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to follow the advice in https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api about importing globals, namely this:

```
However, if you prefer explicit imports, you can do import {describe, expect, it} from '@jest/globals'.
```

It doesn't work, though. I added the import at the top of my two test files and when I run jest, both test suites fail with the message "Do not import @jest/globals outside of the Jest test environment."

I also have jest configured in eslint env, in case it makes a difference.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: @DmitryPapka, I have not yet found a solution for this. I tried the Discord chat channel they suggest but no one replied. In fact, most of the questions there seem to go unanswered, and since SO here isn't getting any answers, I think I'll just open a bug report on their Github repo.

Comment: Actually, I just found out what the problem was: I was importing the Jest globals package in a helper file which isn't a test file. Removing the test file from there and leaving it only in the two test files allows Jest to run without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was: I was importing the @jest/globals package in a helper file which isn't a test file. Removing the import from there and leaving it only in the two test files allows Jest to run without a problem.

Comment: Note: It doesn't necessarily have to be your helper. It can also be a third party lib like vue-test-utils